# runtime errors not showing up in debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, crash, gdb

I've got a couple of programs written in CPP which crash. Some are graphics based, others are command line. Usually they include a while loop and crash after a few minutes.

I attached them to GDB and compiled and executed in Dev C++, and they don't show any sign of crashing. I can run them for hours on end and there are no problems. But once intake it out of that environment they crash in a couple of minutes.

For example I have this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
int main (int argc, char * args[]){
    char sysstr[100];
    if (argc<2){
        printf("No .java file given...");
    }else{
        sprintf(sysstr,"java %s",args[1]);
        try {
            system(sysstr);
        }
        catch (int lol){
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It runs fine within DevC++, but outside windows tells me after it has finished that it stops working.

Help?

Comment: Did you build with symbols?  For GNU compilers, the option is `-g`.

Comment: What does "after it has finished that it stops working" mean?  If it is finished, there no work left for it to do.

Comment: Do you actually expect `system` to `throw` exceptions? If so, perhaps you need to adjust your expectations a little (or a lot)? Also, gdb typically doesn't show errors happening in the program started with `system` and such. And if you have threads in your code, gdb will/may affect how threads interact with your code.

Comment: That was a simple example... I've got a 500+ line piece of SDL code which crashes without warning.